# Where is my money, do i have access to it?

Tags: blockchain

On 10/06/21 I tried to pay for an order with bitcoin. BCH. It went from bitcoin to blockchair to simpleledger:pzt39mmtjfs8trthwvvpq0v7ktjc4wyvyqtdpmf2eh,
Transaction hash [b420f82e47df1d884615a5730958fe1377977f520b69a3388e0eb54df31ac2e6](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20cash/tx/b420f82e47df1d884615a5730958fe1377977f520b69a3388e0eb54df31ac2e6)

I have no idea what these transactions mean.
Can you help me find my money?

Comment: What is simpleledger? It is expecting BTC? It is expecting BCH?

Comment: "Bitcoin" (BTC) is a completely different currency than "Bitcoin Cash" (BCH). This website is for questions about "Bitcoin" (BTC), not for questions about "Bitcoin Cash" (BCH). According to blockchair your recipient has conclusively received your payment (of BCH). If your recipient was not expecting BCH, they might not have any way to access that money and might not accept that payment has been made. Just like sending Japanese Yen to someone expecting US Dollars.